# How to use awk to print every word from a whole string?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, mq

I declared variable (string) containing k names of queues, I want to delete.

How can i "loop" through the string and delete each queue?

I'm having trouble with the awk command.

thanks a lot!

Comment: Assuming you have figured the command to atleast work for you - did you try awk -F ' ' '{print $0}'

Comment: i know this command. it prints the whole string. i want every word in the string to be printed separately. what command can i use for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following command?

```
 awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {printf "%s ", $i}; printf "\n"}' | xargs rm
```

Comment: how can i alter the above command to get every word from the string to put into a new variable and delete the queue i want?

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways, I think the simplest will be

```
$ vars="name1 name2 name3"
$ for v in $vars; do echo $v; done
name1
name2
name3
```

change echo to your script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xargs`:

```
queues="q1 q2 q3 q4"
echo ${queues} | xargs -n1 echo "Remove"
```